# Styles are not showing in React Native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

Styles are not showing in React Native. I'm new to RN so please if you can help me understand ..Here is the code :

```js
import { template } from '@babel/core'
import React from 'react'
import { View , Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    alignItems:'center',
    backgroundColor:'pink',
  },
})
const App = ()=>{
  return(
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hello World!!</Text>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}


export default App
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like this should work. Try changing the text to make sure it's updating. Maybe the simulator has disconnected from your metro bundler.

Comment: @Flagship1442 yes that was the issue. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the answer after half an hour. It's just i needed to rerun the application and it worked. Also *flex :1* helps.